# how to install and config react-native-sass-transformer using expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sass

I need to install and config Saas instead of react-native Stylesheet. I also need to change the style props instead of className.

I've done those steps but it is not working as my expect. 
It works inside of style props. I want to work with className props.

1. npm install --save-dev react-native-sass-transformer node-sass
2. Add this to metro.config.js in your project's root

   ```
   module.exports = (async () => {
     const {
       resolver: { sourceExts }
     } = await getDefaultConfig();
     return {
       transformer: {
         babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-sass-transformer")
       },
       resolver: {
         sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "scss", "sass"]
       }
     };
   })();
   ```
3. If you are using Expo, you also need to add this to app.json

```
  "expo": {
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": ["js", "jsx", "scss", "sass"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to config react native sass transformer

javascript: https://github.com/najathi/expo-sass-transformer-js

typescript: https://github.com/najathi/expo-sass-transformer-ts